# Why would you use な for そう forms of い adjectives?

Tags: adjectives

I am just now really diving into adjectives and how they work in Japanese. It was to my surprise that I heard 『楽{たの}しいそうなお祭{まつ}りね』 being used. Does the そう usage require な even for い adjectives?

Comment: We don't say 楽しいそうなお祭り.  Did you REALLY hear that said by a native speaker?

Comment: I don't remember who said it, but it very well could be by a student. What would you say instead?

Comment: @ヤラユギ There are two different ways to add そう to an i-adjective with very different meanings. You probably meant 楽しそう rather than 楽し**い**そう.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things I would like to do as part of the answer to your question.

First, you may not have been aware that there was a mistake in your sentence.  I will address that first.

You wrote:

> 楽{たの}しいそう

It should be:

> 楽{たの}しそう

For the formation of the そうだ grammar is as follows:

- Vmasu + そうだ
- adj(i/na) stem + そうだ

Examples:

> 話しそう (verb)
>  
>   楽しそう (i adjective)
>   静かそう (na adjective)

<sub>Source: A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar (See below)</sub>

---

Now for the question you acked.  According to [A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/4789004546) (Seiichi Makino and Michio Tsutsui):

> そうだ is a な-type adjective;  The prenominal form is そうな.  Examples:
>
> > 高そうな車
> >     taka souna kuruma
> >     (A car which looks espensive (= an expensive looking car))
> >
> > 雨が降りそうな空
> >     ame ga furi souna sora 
> >     (lit. the sky which looks like it will bring rain)

So to directly answer your question:

> Does the そう usage require な even for い adjectives?

The answer is yes.  Note that most of the time, you will find this formation at the end of a sentence requiring it to end with だ/です.  However, if you plan on using this grammar as an adjective (i.e. you mean to use it to modify a noun), you should treat is as a na-type adjective.

<sub>Note: I included a link to the amazon listing of the book I used for my source.  If you plan to purchase it, look around.  I have definitely seen it sell for less.</sub>

Comment: If you're serious about Japanese then "A Dictionary of xxx Japanese Grammar" is a great investment.